# Filling under the a curve with ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I would like to create a graph with the normal function from x=-2 to x=2 filled under the curve from -2 to 0.
I've tried with ggplot2

```
qplot(c(-2, 2), stat="function", fun=dnorm, geom="line") +
+ geom_area(aes(xlim=c(-2,0)),stat="function", fun=dnorm)
```

But I get this graph completely filled instead (the black colour) 
[image]

How can I get a plot filled only from -2 to 0?

Other options or packages are welcome.

I've also tried with only one command with ggplot and filled option but I can't get it either.
I know some people does it using polygons but the result is not so soft and nice.

PD: I repeat, the solution I'm looking for involves not generating x,y coordinates beforehand but using directly the function with    stat="function", fun=dnorm  or similar.  Thus, my question is not a duplicate.

I've also tried

```
ggplot(NULL,aes(x=c(-2,2))) +  geom_area(aes(x=c(-2,0)),stat="function", fun=dnorm, fill="red") +
geom_area(aes(x=c(0,2)),stat="function", fun=dnorm, fill="blue")
```

But again it fills all the curve with a single color, blue. The red half seems to be overwritten. The same with geom_ribbon and other options.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                xlim = c(-2,0),
                geom = "area")
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this wasn't available when I asked the question.

Answer (score 7):

These days, with `after_stat()` and `after_scale()`, you could also use
a more flexible approach that lets you explicitly map ranges of `x` values
to filled sections.

For example, filling some normal distribution quantiles:

```r
library(ggplot2)

breaks <- qnorm(c(0, .05, .2, .5, .8, .95, 1))

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes(x)) +
  scale_fill_brewer("x") +
  stat_function(
    n = 512,
    fun = dnorm,
    geom = "area",
    colour = "gray30",
    aes(
      fill = after_stat(x) |> cut(!!breaks),
      group = after_scale(fill)
    )
  )
```

[image]

This approach also works with other statistics, e.g. `stat_density()` for kernel density estimates:

```r
set.seed(42)

ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(1000)), aes(x)) +
  scale_fill_brewer("x") +
  stat_density(
    n = 512,
    geom = "area",
    colour = "gray30",
    aes(
      fill = after_stat(x) |> cut(!!breaks),
      group = after_scale(fill)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Can't you generate your distribution data with `dnorm` instead?

```
library(ggplot2)
x<-seq(-2,2, 0.01)
y<-dnorm(x,0,1)
xddf <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
qplot(x,y,data=xddf,geom="line")+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(xddf ,x>-2 & x<0),aes(ymax=y),ymin=0,
              fill="red",colour=NA,alpha=0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, .4))
```

[image]

Comment: But I mean using stat="function" or similar, without generating previously x,y pairs.  I just need to modify my geom_area() function with some parameter

Comment: @skan I not sure how to achieve this with `geom_area`. `geom_ribbon()` seems to work just fine.