# How to annotate the area under the curve of density plot of specific interval?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The density plot is interesting, but the height is just a height. (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147885/how-to-interpret-height-of-density-plot)

So when visualizing this, it's always helpful to provide another information such as what's the percentage for `Sepal.Length` to be between, say, 5 and 6? Shade the area, and annotate the chart with the percentage of that specific area.

How can I do this with ggplot?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length))  + 
    geom_density()
```

[image]

For example below, the area of interest is shaded and it shows the percentage (ideally 12% instead of 0.12)

[image]

Comment: Related, possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33244629/680068

Comment: @zx8754, quite close but not exactly what I want, especially on the annotation part. But thanks, I will have a look at this as well.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the other questions simply shade without annotation provided. As per my title, annotation of the area under the curve is crucial, an image example of the expected result is also provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find `scales::oob_censor()` a convenient function. It converts out-of-bounds values to `NA`s. You can use this to set bounds to the filled area, but also by counting non-NAs, get the fraction of observations falling within the bounds (as closed interval). A downside is that you will get a warning about missing values, which is fine. You'd have to manually set a satisfactory y-value for the text annotation though.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

bounds <- c(5, 6)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length))  + 
  stat_density(geom = "line") +
  stat_density(
    geom = "area",
    aes(x = stage(Sepal.Length, after_stat = oob_censor(x, bounds))),
    alpha = 0.3
  ) +
  annotate(
    "text", mean(bounds), y = 0.2, 
    label = percent(mean(!is.na(oob_censor(iris$Sepal.Length, bounds))))
  )
#> Warning: Removed 370 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Instant fan of your ggh4x as well :), thanks again